# What does “Inni Ka Lillah” and "Inni Qalillah" mean?

Tags: allah, arabic-translation, definitions

I would like to know the usage of Inni Ka Lillah. What is it actually?

Another phrase which confuses me is Inni Qalillah

Is the term controversial, meaning I'm your god?

Comment: Can you edit your answer by adding the exact phrase writen in arabic, so we dont make any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

aww,

Inni ka Lillah does not make sense. It literally mean "I am like for Allah" which is nonsense and not correct grammatically.

You probably mean innaka lillah. Which means, "you belong to Allah", or "you have been created for (the worship of) Allah."